# images vibrate in Google chrome on hover when enlarging with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am currently working on a images gallery now. It is working correctly except in Google Chrome when you hover over the top row, the row beneath will start to vibrate and move. You can find a working example [here](http://codepen.io/Dirkandries/full/vJslk).

**The HTML:**

```
     <div id="gallery">
             <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>"  > 
                           <span c

lass="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>

                      <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>" >
                       <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>
                         <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>" > 
                         <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                            <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>

                        <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>" > 
                        <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>

                      <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>"  >
                       <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>
                         <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>" > 
                         <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>

                      <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>"  >
                       <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>
                         <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>"  >
                          <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>

                         <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>"  >
                          <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>
                        <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>"  > 
                        <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>
                         <a href="<?php echo'?img=$imgname';?>"  > 
                         <span class="title"><?php echo'$imgtitle';?></span>
                             <img src="http://ivojonkers.com/fotorichard/images_slider/1.jpg" />
                        </a>
    </div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#gallery {
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

#gallery a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 12.5px 25px 12.5px;
    position: relative;
    height:150px;
    width:225px;
}

#gallery a img {
    height:150px;
    width:225px;
    position:relative;
}
```

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $("#gallery a img").hover(function(){
            $(this).css({"z-index":"99"}); 
             $(this).stop(true, false).animate({ "margin-left":"-112.5px",
                    "margin-top":"-150px",
                    "bottom":"-75px",
                    "height":"300px",
                    "width":"450px"
                    });
        }, function() {
        $(this).css({"z-index":"0"}); 
             $(this).stop(true, false).animate({"height":"150px",
                    "width":"225px",
                    "margin-left":"0px",
                    "margin-top":"0px",
                    "bottom":"0px"
                 });
        });
});
```

P.S. If you zoom out more it's more noticeable.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome, win8

Comment: i'm currently on the latest version of chrome on win7 and when you hover the top row of img you can see the bottom row start to vibrate

Comment: Windows 7, latest version of chrome and it works great for me.

Comment: it's more noticeable on bigger screens can you try it again after zooming out ( ctrl + - )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with your guys help. All I had to do was change this:

```
    // ...   
$(this).stop(true, false).animate({"height":"150px",
    "width":"225px",
    "margin-left":"0px",
    "margin-top":"0px",
    "bottom":"0px"
}, function(){
    // Do this last
    $(this).css({"z-index":"0"}); 
});
// ...
```

to this:

```
#gallery a img {
height:150px;
width:225px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
}
```

Comment: The answer you accepted as correct does not use this approach, why did you accept that answer as correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option is to duplicate your base image and enlarge it.

```
 $(function() {  
         $("#gallery a img").mouseenter(function(){
           var d = $(this).clone().addClass('preview')
           .css({position:'absolute',top:$(this).position().top, left:$(this).position().left,zIndex:99})
           .insertAfter($(this)).animate({ "margin-left":"-112.5px",
                        "margin-top":"-150px",
                        "bottom":"-75px",
                        "height":"300px",
                        "width":"450px" 
}).mouseleave(function(){
           $(this).animate({"height":"150px",
                        "width":"225px",
                        "margin-left":"0px",
                        "margin-top":"0px",
                        "bottom":"0px"
                                             },
                        function(){$(this).remove()});
            })
           });
    });
```

Try it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbNvu/13/).

Comment: In Chrome negative bottom not working for some reason there, use top instead http://jsfiddle.net/hbNvu/3/

Comment: now the problem is of this script its always finishing the animation in my script its stopping the animation when you leave

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the z-index restore (back to zero) into the animation callback:

```
// ...   
$(this).stop(true, false).animate({"height":"150px",
    "width":"225px",
    "margin-left":"0px",
    "margin-top":"0px",
    "bottom":"0px"
}, function(){
    // Do this last
    $(this).css({"z-index":"0"}); 
});
// ...
```

jsfiddle isn't working for me today for some reason or I'd put one together.

Comment: If you feel I answered your question, please accept it by clicking the check box up there by the vote counter.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This moves all of the images to the right a bit (so just a little extra work), but setting the images to absolute gets rid of the vibrating for me.

```
#gallery a img {
height:150px;
width:225px;
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: This is the better solution IMHO - did a quick test with the Web Inspector and worked like a charm. It's concise.

Answer (score 1):

replace :

```
#gallery a {
display:inline-block;
/* ... */
}
```

with

```
#gallery a {
display:block;
float:left;
/* ... */
}
```